# How can I reset the max-age cache control of my page being redirected ( 302 )

Tags: linux, .htaccess, redirect, redirection

A few hours ago I used the following code in my htaccess to redirect the homepage to a maintenance page:

#### Maintenance redirection

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|js|css) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^92\.95\.110\.92
RewriteRule .* /maintenance/index.html [R=302,L]
```

Then I commented the code out to be able to have the page showing again, however the redirection still took place after changing the access back to previously. I restarted the server as well. Then I checked on an online tool the headers and this is what happens :

```
 Sun, 18 Nov 2018 07:57:58 GMT
Server:
    Apache
Location:
    http://www.website.com/maintenance/index.html
Cache-Control:
    max-age=172800
Expires:
    Tue, 20 Nov 2018 07:57:58 GMT
Content-Length:
    231
Content-Type:
    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Via:
    1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.1), 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.1)
X-Cache-Hits:
    31
X-Cache:
    HIT
Age:
    5602
Connection:
    keep-alive

Redirecting to: http://www.website.com/maintenance/index.html
```

It looks like the 302 redirection is somehow cached until 20 Nov 2018 ?

I have tried to add the following code on the page, restarted the server. No redirection happened, but then the page was totally blank :

```
 <?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Can I reset this "temporary" 302 redirect to stop as soon as possible ? And remove it completely ? I have access to the linux shell. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: This looks like it's a Varnish problem. The default for a 302 redirect is to be non-cacheable. Look at your Varnish configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting me on the right direction. For anyone interested, I had to purge the varnish cash via ssh using : $ curl -X PURGE

Comment: @mlclm Thanks for the feedback, you should add that as an answer (and accept it) - otherwise the question is technically "unanswered" and others may not see the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This looks like it's a Varnish problem. The default for a 302 redirect
>   is to be non-cacheable. Look at your Varnish configuration.

Thanks to @MichaelHampton for the correct answer ,  I had to purge the varnish cash via ssh using : `$ curl -X PURGE –`